# Yesod handlers, content of POSTed files

Tags: haskell, yesod

while the following code:

```
postImportR = do
    fi <- lookupFiles "file"
    fc <- lift $ fileSource (fi !! 0) $$ consume
```

seems to work (at least can I "liftIO $ print fc), splitting it off to a function for iterating doesn't:

```
process :: [FileInfo] -> [String]
process [] = []
process (f:r) = do
    fn <- fileName f
    fc <- lift $ fileSource f $$ consume
    ([fn] : (process r))

postImportR = do
    fi <- lookupFiles "file"
    process fi
```

or even with a lambda function:

```
files <- L.map (\f -> (fileName f, lift $ fileSource f $$ consume)) fi
```

in the Handler it gives me a type error I don't understand.

Where's my fault -- liked to generate content for database import from the file's lines (and to learn some more Haskell, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
fileName :: FileInfo -> Text
```

so you can't directly use `fileName` in a do-block like

```
fn <- fileName f
```

That would need to be a let-binding

```
let fn = fileName f
```

The next thing is what makes `process :: [FileInfo] -> [String]` impossible<sup>(1)</sup>,

```
fileSource :: FileInfo -> Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString
```

so with

```
fc <- lift $ fileSource f $$ consume
```

you are in a do-block whose `Monad` is a `MonadIO`, and you can't get out of a `Monad` that can wrap arbitrary `IO`-actions, just like you can't get out of `IO` itself.

What you can have is

```
process :: (SomeFiendishConstraint m) => [FileInfo] -> m [Text]
process [] = return []
process (f:r) = do
    let fn = fileName f
    lift $ fileSource f $$ consume
    fs <- process r
    return (fn : fs)
```

or, more succinctly,

```
process = mapM (\f -> lift $ fileSource f $$ consume >> return fileName f)
```

and then

```
postImportR = do
    fi <- lookupFiles "file"
    process fi
```

<sup>(1)</sup> Barring `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's great -- but step by step: (1) I know of the difference between "<-" and let-binding, but haven't taken the time to  think enough of the consequences, you're right. (2) As I'm really new to Haskell, I still don't understand good enough, what Monads are and how to deal with it, and (3) your 2nd last line is again an example of one of the different flavours of *map* I still don't have a good idea of. Seems a long way left to go...